# Increase space between line/nodes on d3 collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'd like to customize my d3 chart [collapsible tree](https://codepen.io/fernoftheandes/pen/pcoFz)

Here is the D3 example if you need a source code : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

**I want to have more space between all the lines/nodes**.

```
<rect><text>MyText in a Rectangle</text></rect>
```

How can I achieve this easily using css ?

Best

Comment: Before editing it, you had simply copied the body of your previous question and pasted it here. Is that not the textbook definition of a duplicate question?

Comment: Yes, normal as it is related to the same thing, styling svg with css. That was my question. A question can lead to multiple answers, and an answer fix multiple question

Comment: You could argue that everything in *your* program is related, but the fact remains that you were asking for solutions to multiple problems within the same question.

Comment: The thing is, it is not multiple problems but a single one : "Styling a svg d3 chart". So it is more like multiples css rules, and for me it does not make sense to right 1 question / css rules I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a SVG picture not a regular HTML DOM element. So I am not sure how to use simple CSS to fix it.

But I found an even simpler solution is to just access the separation property of the d3.layout.tree object that is created
. 
On line 126 in your codepen example you just change from:

```
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth; });
```

to

```
.separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5) / a.depth; });
```